# Capturing Filter Data on Interaction Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, filters, interaction-studio

We are trying to capture the filters a user clicks on in the website and use those filters to build some form of affinity towards certain products. We tried making it a user attribute and a product attribute but are unable to find a solution that provides us with what we are looking for. Has anyone ever done something like this?